# Is there a synonym to the phrasal verb "hover down"?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a single word verb and not a phrasal verb like descended slowly or something similar to that. I can't think of a single verb. I think floated doesn't mean that it's moving down slowly.

Comment: *sank lower* or *sank to the ground* maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [glide](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glide) to describe this action:

> to descend gradually in controlled flight

Strictly speaking, *gliding* is more descriptive of a *smooth* action than a *slow* action, but if I wanted to describe an action that is both fast and smooth, I would probably choose [coast](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coast).